# Rexml - Parsing Data

Tags: xml, ruby, rexml

I have a XML File in the following format:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

`<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gwo='http://schemas.google.com/analytics/websiteoptimizer/2009' xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' gd:etag='W/&quot;DUYGRX85fCp7I2A9WxFWEkQ.&quot;'><id>https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/websiteoptimizer/experiments/1025910</id><updated>2010-05-31T02:12:04.124-07:00</updated><app:edited>2010-05-31T02:12:04.124-07:00</app:edited><title>Flow Experiment</title><link rel='gwo:goalUrl' type='text/html' href='http://cart.personallifemedia.com/dlg/download.php'/><link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer'/><link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/websiteoptimizer/experiments/1025910'/><gwo:analyticsAccountId>16334726</gwo:analyticsAccountId><gwo:autoPruneMode>None</gwo:autoPruneMode><gwo:controlScript>`.....

I have to parse and get the data for gd:etag and how do I do it?

I was able to get the value using SimpleXML, but i wanted to achieve it in ReXML.

Please do advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

presumes only one "entry" tag ...

```
require "rexml/document"
include REXML
xml=<<EOD
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gwo='http://schemas.google.com/analytics/websiteoptimizer/2009' xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' gd:etag='W/&quot;DUYGRX85fCp7I2A9WxFWEkQ.&quot;'><id>https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/websiteoptimizer/experiments/1025910</id></entry>
EOD
doc = Document.new xml
doc.elements["entry"].attributes["gd:etag"]
```

see http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/docs/tutorial.html